# ASP.NET to call Python or Bash that resides on RaspberryPi

Tags: c#, asp.net, raspberry-pi

Is it possible to call my Python script or Bash script that resides on my Raspberry Pi from an ASP.NET page?

The ASP.NET application will reside on the same local network but hosted on IIS. It can be a "fire and forget" run if easier.

Comment: Please provide more details, especially where that ASP.NET site is hosted.

Comment: *Much* more detail is required to answer this.